# Wifi Connectivity issue in ubuntu 19.10

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

I am new to Ubuntu and I am using the **Dell Inspiron-5577** laptop. I have a wireless internet connection installed today by my ISP. When I connect through wired connection I was able to get the login portal but when I plug LAN cable to my **Dlink-DIR-600m** router and when I connect to my WiFi, it is showing **?** symbol along with WiFi. I am unable to get the login portal pop up automatically. I was able to connect to my college WiFi and everything was working fine but now I am unable to solve the issue. I have seen so many threads related to the issue but none of them helped. I have restarted the network manager and all but no use, help me please.

Thank you.

Edit:
after performing

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
```

I got the result below:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 [8086:3165] (rev 79)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 [8086:4410]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 i have updated my question with the result

Comment: Your Wi-Fi is OK. Most likely the problem is with your network settings. When you connected without the router you probably have set up some pppoe or other authorization that is not needed with the router.

Comment: @Pilot6 i set up PPPOE only after i was getting the above mentioned problem, like if i connect my lan cable i was able to get the login portal but where as i connect through wifi and type the ip address of the captive portal, i am unable to get it. what do you suggest?

Comment: @Pilot6 should i change my network settings to dynamic ip? or should i reset the router?